# Installing Flutter on Raspberry Pi 4 (8 G.B.)

Tags: flutter, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm using the following article to install Flutter in Raspberry Pi 4
https://snapcraft.io/install/flutter/raspbian#install

I'm getting the following error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo snap install flutter --classic
error: snap "flutter" is not available on stable for this architecture (armhf) but exists on other architectures (amd64, arm64).
```

I tried adding arm64 architecture but couldn't add.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --print-architecture
armhf
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --print-architecture
armhf
```

After attempting to add architecture I again tried to install Flutter

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo snap install flutter --classic
    error: snap "flutter" is not available on stable for this architecture (armhf) but exists on other architectures (amd64, arm64).
```

Comment: I have the same problem… Any solutions?

Comment: Still I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to install a 64 bit image of Raspberry pi OS : https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/

Not sure if it's released yet, but it did the trick and allowed me to install Flutter from Snap.